# Federated queries in SnowFlake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, federated-queries

I have three organizations which want to collaborate. All three of them have the same backend database and tables, and want to run a *federated* query across these three tables. Is that possible using snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

If they each have one "table" each, and [data share](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-sharing-intro.html) it to the other two, that can have the three "tables" and

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM mytable AS a
JOIN their_table_one AS b
JOIN the_other_table AS c
```

just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can import all tables into Snowflake and then create views that combine these tables so that they are visible as one view.

Example:

```sql
CREATE VIEW Table1_v
AS
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'Source A' AS src
  FROM SourceA_Table1
 UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'Source B' AS src
  FROM SourceB_Table1
 UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3, 'Source C' AS src
  FROM SourceC_Table1;
```